# Clicking on tab isn't advancing timer and isn't appending class of active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

> You can view the JSFiddle with code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qf98vgkw/)
>
> You can view the Fullscreen JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qf98vgkw/show/)

Hi guys,

Basically what my issue is, is that I am trying to make it possible for a user to click on the tab and the progress bar will reduce or increase to the appropriate size as well as the class of active will be added to the active slide tab and be removed from any previous one. I will leave the link to a JSFiddle so that you can have a working look at what I am talking about as well as leave my code below.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="omega_player">
    <ul class="omega_slides">
        <li data-slide="1">SLIDE 1</li>
        <li data-slide="2" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
        <li data-slide="3">SLIDE 3</li>
        <li data-slide="4" style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="omega_controls">
        <div class="omega_timer"><div class="progress"></div></div>
        <ul class="omega_tabs">
            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false">Slide 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false">Slide 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false">Slide 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="return false">Slide 4</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="omega_set">
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_play"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_pause"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>
            <a onclick="return false" class="control_next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var increment;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 8000);
    var slideCount = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').length;
    increment=100/slideCount;
    var slideWidth = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').width();
    var slideHeight = $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').height();
    var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
    $('.omega_player').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
    
    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
    
    $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
    progress();
    function moveLeft() {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:last-child').prependTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides').addClass('active');
            progress();
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li').removeClass('active')
        $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:first-child').appendTo('.omega_player>.omega_slides');
            progress();
            $('.omega_player>.omega_slides').css('left', '');
        });
        
    };

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_prev').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide();
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_next').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide();
        moveRight();
    });
    
    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').click(function () {
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').hide();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').show();
        moveRight();
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            moveRight();
        }, 8000);
    });
    
    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').click(function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play').show();
        $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause').hide()
    });

    return timer;

});  

function progress(){
    var activeElement=$('.omega_player>.omega_slides>li:nth-child(2)').attr('data-slide');
    console.log(increment);
    console.log(activeElement);
    var width=(increment*activeElement)+'%';
    console.log(width);
    $('.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_timer>.progress').animate({
         'width':width
    },300);
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.omega_player {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 950px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_slides {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 450px;
list-style: none;
}
.omega_player>.omega_slides>li {
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 950px;
height: 450px;
background: #ccc;
text-align: center;
line-height: 300px;
}

.omega_player>.omega_controls {
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #333;
background: rgba(51,51,51,.8);
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
width: 100%;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set {
position: absolute;
right: -1px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next {
position: absolute;
top: 40%;
z-index: 999;
display: block;
padding: 4% 3%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
background: #2a2a2a;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
opacity: 0.8;
cursor: pointer;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev:hover,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next:hover {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_prev {
border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_next {
right: 0;
border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_pause {
background-color: green;
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>li>.control_play {
display: none!important;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>a {
color: #FFF;
color: rgba(250,250,250,.95);
font-size: 20px;
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 10px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>:hover {
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
color: #FFF;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_prev,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_next,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause {
font-size: 45px;
line-height: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
padding: 0;
text-align: center;
transition: .1s ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid #FFF;
border-color: rgba(250,250,250,0.65);
border-top: 0;
border-bottom: 0;
float: left;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_pause {
border:0;
font-size: 25px;
line-height: 48px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_set>.control_play {
display:none;
}

.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_timer {
background: #333;
background: rgba(51,51,51,.9);
height: 3px;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
min-width: 797px;
width: 797px;
max-width: 797px;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_timer>.progress {
height: 3px;
background-color: #EB0000;
background: rgba(235,0,0,0.86);
max-width: 797px;
z-index: 999;
width: 0%;
transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs {
float: left;
width: 797px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: table;
z-index: 9999;
position: relative;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li>a {
color: #FFF;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
display: block;
padding: 14.5px;
border-left: 1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.75);
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li>a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li>a.active {
font-weight: bold;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li>a:active,
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li>a:focus {
background: none;
}
.omega_player>.omega_controls>.omega_tabs>li:first-child>a {
border: 0;
}
```

I would like to say thanks to anybody in advanced.

> In short when a user clicks a tab they will be taken to the slide corresponding to the tab and also the timer will size appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move to a certain slide, it might be easiest to alter the current sliding to set that slide, instead of incrementing/decrementing the position. moveLeft and moveRight can use the moveTo:

```
var curpos;
function moveTo(pos){
    curpos = Math.abs(pos % slideCount);
    slideholder.animate({
        left: -(curpos-1) * slideWidth
    }, 200, function () {
        slides.removeClass('active').eq(curpos).addClass('active');
        var width=((curpos+1)*increment)+'%';
        progressbar.animate({'width':width},300);
    });
}

function moveLeft() {
    moveTo(curpos + slideCount -1);
};

function moveRight() {        
    moveTo(curpos+1);
};
```

After the moveTo is created, the tabs can simply use their internal index to select the appropriate slide

```
var tabs = $('.omega_tabs > li > a');
tabs.click(function(){
    pause(); //stop timer
    moveTo(tabs.index(this));
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qf98vgkw/1/)

(PS If the number of slides becomes more dynamic, you can also choose to generate the tabs in runtime and assign the slide during creation)

Comment: One last thing how do I get my timer to move slowly along according to the time left to each slide? But when paused it will sit a solid block above each slide?